# make_plan going to bizzarre locations in path

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have stage running with gmapping and move_base.  I am using a 1 meter resolution on the map, and I invoke the make_plan service from move stage and it gives me bizzare locations.

For example I use:
'{ start: {header: {stamp: now, frame_id: base_link}, pose:{position: [0.0,0.0,0.0], orientation: [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}}, goal: {header: {stamp: now, frame_id: base_link}, pose:{position: [5.0,5.0,0.0], orientation: [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]}},tolerance: 20}'

and the resulting  path gave me a position at 12, -6.

I have tried this with and without amcl.  The only error I get is from move_base which says:

> [ WARN] [1304214340.248802176, 1776.700000000]: The goal sent to the navfn planner is off the global costmap. Planning will always fail to this goal.

But the point should not be off the costmap it is 192 X 192.

Any suggestions, I would rather use move_base than write my own A* algorithm on the costmap but I am running out of options.

Thanks in advance,
~BM

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9854/make_plan-going-to-bizzarre-locations-in-path./) by [BlackManta](https://answers.ros.org/users/428/blackmanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Are you sure you are using a static map as global costmap?
Could you post your config files for move_base as well as the yaml file for your map?
Seems to me that your origin it somehow different than the left bottom corner.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2